# Can we convert an image to xaml using expression blend?

Tags: image, xaml, expression-blend

I had a design in a image, I need the same design in my windows phone application. I googled there's a lot of tool available to convert image to xaml.

But my question is there a way to convert without using those tools and using Microsoft's Expression Blend.

can we export them directly, if yes say me some info to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Expression Design to directly open your images irrespective of the designing tool, In Design there's a option called Export as xaml.

Refer these links [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/cc197104.aspx) and [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294508.aspx)

Hope it helps!

Comment: that simply wraps the image into into a container. It does not do conversion to path expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the import function in Expression Blend.
Assuming you are developing a Windows Phone 8 app, you have three import options:

- Adobe Illustrator AI
- Adobe FXG
- Adobe Photoshop PSD

In short, what the import allows you depends on what you are trying to import. Mostly they lets you import "Adobe Paths" and translate into XAML Paths.

If you have a jpg image illustrating how your future app should look like, you are best of with designing and developing it- for this I can highly recommend Expression Blend.

Collaborating between the Adobe Suite and Expression Blend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd835382.aspx

Take a look at http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/design for information on how to get started.